# Swift - C API bridge - how to handle null pointers

Tags: c, swift, option-type

In Swift I am using C API that returns struct with char array (containing UTF8 null terminated string or null).

```
struct TextStruct {
   char * text;
   //other data
}
```

I use:

```
let text: String = String(cString: data.text)
```

This works, however, when `data.text` is `nullptr`, this fails with

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Is there any workaround, or I have to check `data.text` manually before using `cString` ctor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to [Gwendal Roué's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47375419/1187415): You can 
*annotate* the C API to indicate whether the pointer can be null or not.
For example,

```
struct TextStruct {
    char * _Nullable text;
    //other data
};
```

is imported to Swift as

```
public struct TextStruct {
    public var text: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?
    // ...
}
```

where `var text` is a "strong" optional instead of an implicitly
unwrapped optional. Then

```
let text = String(cString: data.text)
// value of optional type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?' not unwrapped; ...
```

no longer compiles, and forces you to use optional binding or 
other unwrapping techniques, and the *"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil"*
cannot happen anymore accidentally.

For more information, see ["Nullability and Objective-C"](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25) from the Swift Blog –
despite the title, it can be used with pure C as well.

Comment: I assume following this approach would be safer :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you have to check data.text, in order to make sure it can feed the `String(cString:)` initializer, which is **[documented](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1641523-init) to require a non-null pointer**.

A technique is to use a `if let` statement. This is a classic technique for safely unwrapping optional values:

```
let str: String?
if let ptr = ptr {
    str = String(cString: ptr)
} else {
    str = nil
}
print("got \(str ?? "nil")")
```

Another technique is the `Optional.map` function:

```
let str = ptr.map { String(cString: $0) }
print("got \(str ?? "nil")")
```

Comment: `char * text;` is imported to Swift as implicitly unwrapped optional `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>!`. In order to use Optional.map you have to assign it to a strong optional first.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the address of the pointer is set

```swift
let textIsSet = Int(bitPattern: data.text) != 0

let text: String? = textIsSet ? String(cString: data.text) : nil
```