# How to extend String's UnsafePointer<Int8> initializer to accept NULL pointers?

Tags: swift, string, pointers, unsafe-pointers

In Swift, there's a String initialiser that takes an `UnsafePointer<Int8>` (or `UnsafePointer<CChar>` which is the same I think) as an argument.

However, there's no initialiser that takes an optional `UnsafePointer`, e.g. a pointer that's `NULL` (or nil, speaking swifty), which can be extremely helpful when working with a C API.

I'd like to extend the String class to accept optional unsafe pointers.

This is what my extension looks like. Is that correct? Is this how one would implement that feature?

```swift
extension String {
    init?(cString: UnsafePointer<Int8>?) {
        guard let cString = cString else { return nil }
        self = String(cString: cString)
    }
}
```

Comment: That is exactly how I would do it.

Comment: An alternative (using Optional.map instead of a custom initializer) is demonstrated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47375419/1187415.

Comment: Indeed, thanks, I find this is more convenient though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's fine. You have a failable initializer which “fails” (returns `nil`) if the given argument is `nil`. Otherwise it unwraps the argument and initializes the string by assigning to `self` (which can be done with `struct` types).

`CChar` is indeed the same type as `Int8` on all Apple platforms (where `char` is a *signed* character). I would write the argument type as `UnsafePointer<CChar>?` to emphasize the connection with the `char` type in C.

A (only slightly different) alternative is

```
extension String {
    init?(cString: UnsafePointer<CChar>?) {
        guard let cString = cString else { return nil }
        self.init(cString: cString)
    }
}
```

but that is purely a matter of taste.